# WebClient HTML Differing From Chrome View

Tags: c#, google-chrome, internet-explorer, webclient

I have the following code:

```
            using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                string webPageContent = webClient.DownloadString("https://www.google.com.au/search?q=online+title+search&num=3");
            }
```

When I copy the `webPageContent` into Notepad and save as .html, and view in Chrome, the list of search results is different to what is displayed in Chrome if I hit that URL.

Here are some screenshots:

WebClient output displayed in Chrome:
[image: WebClient output displayed in Chrome]

URL directly accessed in Chrome:
[image: URL directly accessed in Chrome]

As you can see the WebClient output is not the same as the Chrome output, however I noticed if you hit the URL directly in IE, the output is the same as `webPageContent`:

URL directly accessed in IE:
[image: URL directly accessed in IE]

Why does Chrome and IE have different outputs, and how can I configure `WebClient` to output the same content as what is displayed in Chrome?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `user-agent` header?

Comment: Html pages layout is established after a number of "considerations" (see: [Content Negotiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation)). Scripts, active both server-side and client-size, determine the final visual result, to achieve the best possible user experience with the Browser in use. "Lie" about the User-Agent, setting your WebClient's underlying `HttpWebRequest` `UserAgent` Header. (For FireFox: `WebClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0");`. You can find common user-agent strings online.